# \FileSystem\srvnet preventing computer sleep

Tags: windows-7

I have what appears to be a pretty common issue. Basically, most of the computers on my company network won't go to sleep. After a lot of testing (disabling shared services, multimedia stream, etc...) I found out that the problem comes from the network. This is the report of

```
powercfg -requests

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
Nessuna.

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] \FileSystem\srvnet
Un client remoto attivo ha recentemente inviato richieste a questo computer.

AWAYMODE:
Nessuna.

ESECUZIONE:
Nessuna.

PERFBOOST:
Nessuna.
```

Sorry for it being in Italian. Now, if I set standby to 1 minute it won't work. I tried starting the PC with the network cable plugged out and with the wireless connection disabled. Guess what: the standby works brilliantly. If I plug the ethernet cable in it reappears immediately. How can I diagnose where the issue is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was Watchguard's Single Sign On Agent, which was contacting clients continuously. Had to uninstall and disable the thing from my server.